# Do I need to pay tax on my unregistered online 'business'?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, international, sales-tax, ecommerce

Let's say I have an online store. I sell things and receive revenue. It is profitable. Its server is somewhere in USA. I am currently in Germany. My customers are mostly in, say, Thailand. I have not registered it as a company, all the monies goes into different accounts in different countries (as I see fit). I have dual citizenship of UK and Hong Kong.

Do I need to pay tax? (What kind of tax? Business tax as well as personal income taxes?) If so ***who*** do I pay it to? Is it to the country where my bank accounts are? Is it to the country where I live? Where my server is hosted?

Comment: `I have not registered it as a company` So you aren't a business yet. You have to pay tax, why do you think you don't have to. You will be treated under UK laws and any tax arrangements existing between UK and Thailand. You will pay taxes in both places, but under the tax aggrement between the 2 countries. I would say meet an accountant pronto. This will become complicated the more you let it fester.

Comment: Question: Why should who I pay taxes to depend on where my customers are?

Comment: You are doing business in a country. You do need to pay taxes there, albeit accordingly how it is defined in the tax treaty between both the countries.

Comment: I'd suggest Germany would expect tax from you, too, if you are resident there while receiving income from your business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you do.

You're under the jurisdiction of at least one country where you're resident, or where you're citizen. You may be under jurisdiction of more than one country. Each country has its own laws about what and how should be taxed and countries have treaties between them to resolve jurisdiction issues and double taxation situations, so you should talk to a tax accountant licensed to provide you with an advice.